# Implementing a custom file namespace scheme in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel, vfs

Is it possible to create a new, arbitrary, file namespace scheme in Windows?

As best I understand, Windows currently understands two or three file system or file-system-like namespace schemes:

- The namespace scheme we all know and love, eg, C:\path\to\file.
- UNC paths, eg, \\server\path\to\file
- One, perhaps uncommon scheme - the Windows NT Object Manager, eg, \\.\Device\COM1 - see [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) on SysInternals, usually accessed by programs by calling [CreateFile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831), though this is not really a file system.

Is it possible to implement a custom namespace scheme that would be universally, automatically used by the rest of the operating system? Perhaps a filter driver or some other specialized kernel-mode driver? I'm out of my league here, but I'm genuinely curious.

I don't have anything concrete, but lets say I wanted to implement a kernel driver that, not only understands how to read and write OpenVMS file systems, but also implements some sort of filter driver so that userland programs could use standard [File-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11) syntax to access such a filesystem.

For example, an existing program calls `OpenFile("[DIR1.DIR2.DIR3]FILE.EXT;10");` and somehow a custom handler deals with it transparently, and lo, notepad can read and write VMS files. More importantly, perhaps, some ported program that expects OpenVMS File-11 path strings just works. Simply mapping the OpenVMS file system into the regular windows file system as `D:\dir1\dir2\file.ext` would be insufficient.

I should clarify that my OpenVMS reference is just an example; I'd be looking for a more generic solution. This could be for OpenVMS File-11, MVS, standard unix syntax ala `/path/to/thing`, or something I just cooked up myself.

I'm aware of shell-based [namespace extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_extension#Extensibility), and compatibility layers like cygwin, but that's not what I'm looking for.

So SO, what do you think? Is this possible? Where do you start?

Comment: Yes, it's possible; no, it's not easy; and the app-compat burden would be *enormous*.  What you ask for is effectively building a new subsystem (because ported programs are going to want more than simple filename syntax).  Windows Explorer isn't going to know how to navigate that thing.

Comment: It will if you implement a custom Shell Namespace Extension.